# Applying the copy-swap idiom to humans and employees

Tags: c++, object-oriented, c++11, memory-management, constructor

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) post which explains the copy and swap idiom. However I could not find this idiom applied to classes that have base classes. Following is my attempt of a copy-swap idiom applied to class constructors and assignment operators. In the following code class `employee` inherits from class `human` - The constructors and assignment operators of both the classes are quite similar in manner. I am more interested in making this a generic class. If you have solid suggestions about exception safety please let me know. I would like to keep the code to a minimum to serve as a guiding principal for further classes. I also understand that using a `char *` is not recommended for a C++ project however most of the projects that I have come across use a `char*` here and there.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class details
{
   std::string optional_info;
};


class human
{
  public:
  char *blood_type=nullptr;
  std::string dob = "";
  details* di = nullptr;

  //This is the swap method
  void swap(human& lhs , human& rhs)
  {
    std::swap(lhs.blood_type , rhs.blood_type);
    std::swap(lhs.dob , rhs.dob);
    std::swap(lhs.di , rhs.di);
  }


  public:

  //Regular constructor
  human() {/*...*/}

  human(const human& f)
  {
     //Copy the blood_type char pointer
     if(f.blood_type != nullptr) {
     blood_type =  new char[std::strlen(f.blood_type) + 1];
     strcpy(blood_type, f.blood_type);
     }

     //Copy the string
     this->dob = f.dob;

     //Copy the object detail
     this->di = new details(*(f.di));
  }

  //Assignment operator
  human& operator=(human& f)
  {
     if(this != &f)               //Make sure they are not the same
     {
        human temp = f;            //Call the copy constructor
        swap(*this,temp);          //Swap the values;
     }
     return *this;
  }

  //Move copy constructor
  human(human&& f)
  {
    swap(*this , f);
  }

  //Move copy constructor
  human& operator=(human&& f)
  {
    swap(*this , f);
    return *this;
  }

  ~human()
  {
     if(blood_type!=nullptr)
        delete blood_type;
     if(di!=nullptr)
         delete di;
  }
};



class employee : public human
{
  public:
  char *duty=nullptr;
  std::string title="";
  details* detail=nullptr;;

  //This si the swap method
  void swap(employee& lhs , employee& rhs)
  {
    std::swap(lhs.duty , rhs.duty);
    std::swap(lhs.title , rhs.title);
    std::swap(lhs.detail , rhs.detail);
  }


  public:
  //Regular constructor
  employee() {/*...*/}

  //Copy constructor
  //Since we provided a custom copy constructor we should also
  //call the copy constructor of the base class using initialization list
  //If we do not do that the regular constructor of base class will be called.
  employee(const employee& f) : human(f) //This will call the copy constructor of base class
  {
     //Copy the address char pointer
     if(f.duty != nullptr) {
     duty =  new char[std::strlen(f.duty) + 1];
     strcpy(duty, f.duty);
     }

     //Copy the string
     this->title = f.title;

     //Copy the object detail
     this->detail = new details(*(f.detail));
  }

  //We need to copy the base class too.
  //Assignment operator
  employee& operator=(employee& f)
  {
     if(this != &f)               //Make sure they are not the same
     {
        employee temp = f;             //Call the copy constructor
        human::operator=(temp); //<---Design question regarding this at end.
        swap(*this,temp);         //Swap the values;
     }
     return *this;
  }

  //Move copy constructor
  employee(employee&& f) : human( std::move( f))    //call move constructor of base class
  {
    //Important
    //Now f is an lvalue (since it has a name) that is holding an rvalue.
    swap(*this , f);
  }

  //Move copy constructor
  //Rvalue reference to hold temporaries as parameter
  employee& operator=(employee&& f)
  {
    human::operator=(std::move(f)); //Call assignment operator of base classa
    swap(*this , f);
    return *this;
  }

  ~employee()
  {
     if(duty!=nullptr)
        delete duty;
     if(detail!=nullptr)
         delete detail;
  }
};
```

Questions:

1. Does this class comply with the copy-swap idiom? Is anything missing or overlooked?
2. I noticed that the assignment operator in the above class could use improvements. For instance, first it creates a deep copy of the object using its copy constructor (during which a copy of the base class is made) after that the following call is made:

   ```
   human::operator=(temp) ;
   ```

   This statement calls the copy assignment operator of the base class which in return makes another deep copy using its own copy constructor. I wanted to know if there was a better way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However I could not find this idiom applied to classes that have base classes.

**TL;DR: Don't mix value semantics with polymorphism.** You can't sensibly `swap()` two humans, because you can't sensibly swap an employee with a non-employee (even though both are humans). I say a lot more about this, far below, after we get through the basic copy-and-swap stuff.

> 1. Does this class [`human`] comply with the copy-swap idiom? Is anything missing or overlooked?

Your copy constructor for `human` is exception-unsafe.
Here are the members that need copying:

```
char *blood_type = nullptr;
std::string dob = "";
details *di = nullptr;
```

And here is your implementation, for ease of reference. I've adjusted the whitespace for readability, and removed redundant comments, but not changed any of the non-whitespace characters:

```
  human(const human& f)
  {
     if (f.blood_type != nullptr) {
         blood_type =  new char[std::strlen(f.blood_type) + 1];
         strcpy(blood_type, f.blood_type);
     }

     this->dob = f.dob;  // may throw std::bad_alloc [1]

     this->di = new details(*(f.di));  // may throw std::bad_alloc [2]
  }
```

The explicit call to `operator new` on line [2] might throw, in which case you'd leak `this->blood_type`. Or, the implicit allocations inside `std::string::operator=` on line [1] and `std::string::string(const string&)` on line [2] might throw, in which case you'd leak `this->blood_type` and/or `this->di`.

In practice, you would use `std::unique_ptr` and/or `std::string` to manage all your memory, and then you could rely on the [Rule of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/). But let's say you can't do that for some reason. Then a correct implementation of your copy constructor would look like this:

```
human(const human& f) : dob(f.dob)
{
    try {
        if (f.blood_type != nullptr) {
            blood_type = new char[std::strlen(f.blood_type) + 1];
            strcpy(blood_type, f.blood_type);
        }
        di = new details(*f.di);
    } catch (...) {
        delete [] blood_type;
        delete di;
        throw;
    }
}
```

Your copy-assignment operator is *almost* correct, but you're missing a `const` on the argument.

```
  human& operator=(const human& f) {
     if (this != &f) {
        human temp = f;
        swap(*this, temp);
     }
     return *this;
  }
```

Your move constructor and move-assignment operator (not "move copy constructor"; there's no such thing) implemented as "move by swapping" are both correct.

Your `swap` function itself, however, is confused. You've made it a non-static member function, called as `alice.swap(bob, charlie)`. You should instead make it a [`friend` free function](http://b.atch.se/posts/non-constant-constant-expressions/#friends):

```
friend void swap(human& lhs, human& rhs) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs.blood_type, rhs.blood_type);
    swap(lhs.dob, rhs.dob);  // [3]
    swap(lhs.di, rhs.di);
}
```

Notice that I'm using the `using std::swap` ADL idiom, which means that the `swap` invoked on line [3] is `swap(string&, string&)` and not `swap<string>`. If you screw up and accidentally write `std::swap(lhs.dob, rhs.dob)`, you will invoke **undefined behavior** in the case that `&lhs == &rhs`, because you'll be attempting to move a `std::string` into itself. *(N4296 contains contradictory wording on the subject, but as of Lenexa it has [been amended](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2063) to clarify that indeed `std::string` does not support self-move.)*  If you're at all unsure whether `swap(foo, foo)` does the right thing for some member `foo`, please do wrap your whole swap routine in an extra layer of `if (&lhs != &rhs)`.

Lastly, your destructor should be written as

```
~human() {
    delete [] blood_type;  // use the correct operator delete[]
    delete di;
}
```

There's no need to test for `nullptr` first; the built-in `operator delete` and `operator delete[]` are guaranteed to do the right thing (i.e. nothing) when you pass in `nullptr`.

> 2. I noticed that the assignment operator in the above class [i.e. `employee`] could use improvements.

Yes; IMHO it's *really* sketchy to depart from the Rule of Zero in a child class. Make the new members

```
std::string duty = "";
std::string title = "";
details detail = {};
```

and the whole problem goes away. But again, for pedagogical purposes, let's assume you can't do that.

```
void swap(employee& lhs, employee& rhs)
{
    std::swap(lhs.duty, rhs.duty);
    std::swap(lhs.title, rhs.title);
    std::swap(lhs.detail, rhs.detail);
}
```

Again this should be a `friend` free function, not a non-static member function. However, it's got problems:

```
employee alice, bob;
alice.dob = "1/1/1990"; bob.dob = "4/2/1942";
swap(alice, bob);
assert(alice.dob == "1/1/1990");  // oops!
```

`swap` doesn't swap the parts of the `employee` that make them `human`!
But then if we change `swap` to also swap the `human` part, we find that we've broken your assignment operator...

```
employee(employee&& f)
    : human(std::move(f))   // swaps the human parts
{
    swap(*this, f);         // swaps the human parts back!
}
```

The right fix here is to apply the "move by swapping" idiom to your `employee` move constructor as well. You don't need to keep mentioning the fact that an `employee` is a `human`.

```
employee(employee&& f)  // default-construct all the parts
{
    swap(*this, f);         // swap all the parts at once
}

employee& operator=(employee&& f)
{
    swap(*this, f);
    return *this;
}
```

So then how do we write `swap` correctly for an `employee`? Well, that gets us back to the problem that we're trying to mix inheritance with value semantics, and C++ doesn't like that. [See this SO question for some background.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822876/c-swap-problem-in-inheritance-scenario) For example:

```
employee alice;
human atouk;
swap(atouk, alice);  // swap(human&, human&)
```

The above code compiles, since `alice`, being an `employee`, is-a `human`. However, we end up [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) away all the things that make `alice` an `employee`; Atouk takes over Alice's duties, and it's pretty much just a terrible state of affairs.

So, **don't try to mix inheritance hierarchies with value semantics!** They don't play well together.

However, if we trust our users to swap employees only with other employees, we can at least get the correct semantics via

```
friend void swap(employee& lhs, employee& rhs) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(static_cast<human&>(lhs), static_cast<human&>(rhs));
    swap(lhs.duty, rhs.duty);
    swap(lhs.title, rhs.title);
    swap(lhs.detail, rhs.detail);
}
```

So our whole `employee` class looks like this:

```
class employee : public human
{
  public:
    char *duty = nullptr;
    std::string title = "";
    details *detail = nullptr;

    friend void swap(employee& lhs, employee& rhs) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(static_cast<human&>(lhs), static_cast<human&>(rhs));
        swap(lhs.duty, rhs.duty);
        swap(lhs.title, rhs.title);
        swap(lhs.detail, rhs.detail);
    }

    employee() { /*...*/ }

    employee(const employee& f) : human(f), title(f.title)
    {
        try {
            if (f.duty != nullptr) {
                duty = new char[std::strlen(f.duty) + 1];
                strcpy(duty, f.duty);
            }
            detail = new details(*f.detail);
        } catch (...) {
            delete [] duty;
            delete detail;
            throw;
        }
    }

    employee(employee&& f) {
        swap(*this, f);  // default-construct-and-then-swap
    }

    employee& operator=(const employee& f) {
        if (this != &f) {
            employee temp = f;  // copy-...
            swap(*this, temp);  // ...-and-swap
        }
        return *this;
    }

    employee& operator=(employee&& f) {
        swap(*this, f);  // move-by-swapping
        return *this;
    }

     ~employee() {
         delete [] duty;
         delete detail;
     }
 };
```